# Python: How to perform linear regression of two numpy 3D datasets along axis?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I have two datasets of a specific region: The first is the rainfall and the second a vegetation measure (npp) of that region. So, the first two dimensions (x,y) represent the geographical location. The third dimension is the time (8 time steps). What I want to do is to perform a linear regression for each location of the 8 values rainfall versus the 8 values of the vegetation. The result should be  either several two dimensional arrays in which for each location the p-value, the r², the slope and ideally the residuals  are calculated or all values togeher in a 3D array.

```
nppList = glob.glob(nppPath+"*.img")
rainList = glob.glob(rainPath+"*.img")

nppImg = [gdal.Open(i) for i in nppList]
rainImg = [gdal.Open(i) for i in rainList]

nppFiles = [i.ReadAsArray() for i in nppImg]
rainFiles = [i.ReadAsArray() for i in rainImg]

# get nodata
nppNodata = nppImg[1].GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
rainNodata = rainImg[1].GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()

# convert to float and set no data
nppStack = nppStack.astype(float)
nppStack[nppStack == nppNodata] = np.nan
rainStack = rainStack.astype(float)
rainStack[rainStack == rainNodata] = np.nan

# instead of range(0,8) there should be the rainfall variable, but on a pixel base
def linReg(a):
    return stats.linregress(a, range(0, 8))

lm = np.apply_along_axis(linReg, axis=2, arr=nppStack)
```

I know the function numpy.apply_along_axis() but here a function can be applied to only one array. I am searching for a possibility to apply a function on two arrays along an axis preferably wihtout looping through the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source for `scipy.stats.linregress`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3075) indicates that only arrays with dimension greater than 2 are not supported (and only then for the case that your x and y data happen to be in the same data structure).

Honestly, in your case I would use a Python loop -- it is unlikely that the slowest part of the code is looping over the data points; rather, the regression itself will be determining the speed.

In that case, you could flatten your positional axes, use a single loop, and then reshape the regression results back to 3D. Something like:

```
n = nx * ny
frain = rainStack.reshape((n, 8))
fnpp = nppStack.reshape((n, 8))
reg_results = np.empty((n,5))
for i in range(n):
    reg_results[i] = stats.linregress(frain[i], fnpp[i])
reg_results[i].reshape((nx,ny,8))    # back to 3D
```

Comment: Thanks! Except for one thing this suggestion works fine: 
`code' reg_results = np.empty((n,5))  # stats.lienregress returns 5 values`
Unfortunately, my arrays are very large and I was hoping to find a much faster solution

Comment: Good point - I've edited my solution. You might try profiling, but I really don't think that the Python loop over location is the bottleneck here.